# What is the difference between Code Review and Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I know Stack Overflow and Code Review are sites intended for two separate purposes, as the names suggest. However, I don't see any difference on how people ask and answer here compared to Stack Overflow.

What is accepted on Code Review but not on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Short answer: compare the two FAQs.  Long answer: SO handles actual errors in code (compiler or run-time).  However, they, or anyone else (I think), won't look for errors themselves.  You have to do that yourself.  You can also ask them about example code or algorithms.  However, for CR, only working code is acceptable.  Specifically, no aforementioned errors to be found (to the best of your knowledge).  You must also post actual code, not pseudo-code.  You can get help with the design of your code, if it's correct or not, or if it's inefficient and/or contains security holes.

Comment: Ok so in sense, CR is for good code, and StackOverflow is for code with errors (usually)

Comment: Yep!  Many off-topic questions (even containing code) posted here are about errors in code.  We generally encourage those people to get their errors corrected over there, then post their working code here if they want additional feedback.

Answer (score 4):

The main differences between the two sites, near as I can see, is that CR is for code that DOES works. It accomplishes what you want. Yet, you want to make sure you're doing it effeciently, or just maybe want to find a better way. SO is for code that DOESN'T work. You post your code there, in the hopes that a fresh pair of eyes can help solve the issues.